# Catching exception when retrieving data from sqlite database Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this on my DBHelper

```
public Cursor selectUser(String username){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE username = '" +
            username+"'", null);
    return res;
}
```

And i also have this try-catch block on my Activity.

```
DBHelper mydb;
Cursor res;
user = LoginActivity.usernamee;        
    try{
                res = mydb.selectUser(user);
                if(res.getCount() > 0){
                    String fullnamee = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.USER_NAME));
                    fullname.setText(fullnamee);
                    fullname.setFocusable(false);
                    fullname.setClickable(false);
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error retrieving database record.");
            }
```

However, I am getting the catch exception. What I am trying to do is that, I would like to check my database where username is equal to `LoginActivity.usernamee`. Then display the full name of the user from my database table to my Android text view.

I would like to ask for assistance. Thank you!

Comment: From your current block of code, I don't see you initialize `DBHelper` Instead of printing a generic error in your `catch`, you should get the error message from the exception. It'll help you debug any problems.

Comment: The exception object contains useful information. Why are you throwing it away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are missing "moveToFirst"

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE username = '" + username + "'", null);

if(res.getCount() > 0){
  res.moveToFirst();
  String fullnamee = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.USER_NAME));
  // do what you want
}
```